# How to create variables in AWS and use them in an .env file for ECS deploy task

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

One of my former workplaces used this kind of functionality. They had a production.env file in config folder and the docker image copied that production.env file into the container when deploying through Github tasks.

```
DATABASE_HOST=$DATABASE_HOST
DATABASE_PORT=$DATABASE_PORT
DATABASE_USERNAME=$DATABASE_USERNAME
DATABASE_PASSWORD=$DATABASE_PASSWORD
DATABASE_NAME=$DATABASE_NAME
```

It seems like they created these variables on AWS somehow, and used them directly in the production.env file. I can't find any references to this on google, as I'm not sure what to search.

Comment: It looks like those values are probably defined as environment variables in the ECS task definition.

Comment: That's what I thought as well, and googled, but I couldn't find it in the AWS UI. Any idea how to navigate there and add them? @MarkB

Comment: You go to the ECS service console, and then click on the task definitions link.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject individual name/value pairs or entire files via your ECS task definitions. See the documentation here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/taskdef-envfiles.html

Alternatively if you need more detailed configuration management, you can inject environment variables from [SSM Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/specifying-sensitive-data-parameters.html) and [Secrets Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/specifying-sensitive-data-secrets.html) in similar ways.